# Perturbation evolution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, inequality, perturbation-theory, stability-in-odes

Let $a$, $b$ be two real positive parameters with $a>b$, and consider the following nonlinear differential equation:
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_{\varepsilon}(t) = a - b\sin(x_{\varepsilon}(t))+\varepsilon, \quad x_\varepsilon(0)\in\mathbb{R},
\end{align}
where $\varepsilon$ is a real constant.
Let us define 
$$
\Delta(t,\varepsilon):= |\cos({x}_{\varepsilon}(t))-\cos({x}_{0}(t))|
$$
Clearly, note that $\Delta(t,0)\equiv 0$.

> Is it true that $\Delta(t,\varepsilon)$ is linearly bounded in $t\ge 0$ and $|\varepsilon|$, that is
>   $$
>  \Delta(t,\varepsilon)\le K |\varepsilon| t,
> $$
>   where $K$ being a suitable constant? [In case the answer is no, is it possible to find upper bound such that $\Delta(t,\varepsilon)\le K |\varepsilon| p(t)$ where $p(t)$ is a polynomial function of $t$?]

Numerical simulations seem to confirm this claim. Any help towards a theoretical confirmation (or rejection) of this claim is more than welcome! Many thanks!

---

**An initial (incomplete) attempt.** We can rewrite $\Delta(t,\varepsilon)$ as
$$
\Delta(t,\varepsilon)= 2\left|\sin\left(\frac{{x}_{\varepsilon}(t)-{x}_{0}(t)}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{{x}_{\varepsilon}(t)+{x}_{0}(t)}{2}\right)\right|,
$$
so that 
$$
\Delta(t,\varepsilon)\le 2\left|\sin\left(\frac{{x}_{\varepsilon}(t)-{x}_{0}(t)}{2}\right)\right|\le |{x}_{\varepsilon}(t)-{x}_{0}(t)|.
$$
So now the problem is perhaps a bit simplified (?) and boils down to find an upper bound to $|{x}_{\varepsilon}(t)-{x}_{0}(t)|$. However, I don't know how to proceed from here.